# Regex to determine if one string is included in another (n characters)

Tags: regex

I have to implement a rule about passwords. The rule say that the new password must not be included in the old one. Specification say we consider an inclusion from at least 4 consecutive characters. I'm looking for a **regex** , not java implementation.

Example :

```
OLD_PASSWORD = "Support1234"
NEW_PASSWORD = "Support567" <-- not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "Support" <-- not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "Suppression" <-- not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "Supersport" <-- not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "123port" <--  not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "1234" <--  not allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "123pork" <--  allowed
NEW_PASSWORD = "pork123" <--  allowed
```

This kind of regex is a bit complex, I tried something like that : `[^OLD_PASSWORD]{4}` but It's not so easy.

To summarize:  my string should not contain 4 consecutive characters of a determined string in order to pass validation
Please help thx :)

Comment: Cut in possible chunks the old password then use indexOf

Comment: Something like that may work `S?u?p?p?o?r?t?5?6?7?`

Comment: @RC. I could, but i don't like this method.. Moreover I use spring and i pref use a simple Pattern annotation on class

Comment: @Tim007 , no because with this pattern i totally break the "consecutive 4 characters" rule :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lest say that the password length always >4 char, we can take the first 4 char from the old pass and then compare it every 4 next char until the end of oldpassword length.

```
Boolean found = false;
int l = 0, r = 4;
while( found == false && r <= oldpass.length()){
    String tmp = oldpass.substring(l,r);
    found = newpass.contains(tmp);
    l++; r++;
}
```

Take in mind that substring take from l to r-1. After that you can check the found boolean :)

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, this solution doesn't satisfy me because i'm in Spring and i would use a simple pattern anotation, this way is easier for further modification . That's why I ask for a regex :p

Comment: Finally I resolved my self too do this in java , with a similar treatment but it still not satisfy me , but you got the point ^^

Answer (score 0):

Convert new password to Pattern newPasswordPattern = "([1]?[2]?[3]?[p]?[o]?[r]?[t]?)";
Find matches in old one and check their lengths.